# For which finite groups $G$ is $M_n(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta))$ a factor of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I have cross-posted this question on Math Overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457967/for-which-finite-groups-g-is-m-n-mathbbq-zeta-a-factor-of-mathbbq).

For a finite group $G$, the rational group ring $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ has a *Wedderburn decomposition*:
$$
\mathbb{Q}[G] \cong \prod_{i=1}^k M_{n_i}(D_i),
$$
where $D_i$ is a division algebra whose center is a number field, and $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ is the ring of $n_i \times n_i$ matrices over $D_i$.  I will refer to the factors of this product as the *simple factors* of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$.  Each simple factor corresponds to an irreducible $\mathbb{Q}$-representation of $G$.

My question is: given $n$ and a primitive $d$th root of unity $\zeta_d$, for which finite groups $G$ does $M_n(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d))$ appear as a simple factor of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ corresponding to a *faithful* representation of $G$?

It is well known that if $G$ is cyclic of order $d$, then the unique faithful irreducible representation of $G$ has $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d)$ as its corresponding simple factor.
Moreover, if $G$ is a Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then it has a unique faithful irreducible representation; computer experiments (using the GAP package `wedderga`) seem to suggest that the corresponding simple factor is $M_p(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p))$.

What other examples are there?

Answer (score 2):

I will prove the statement when $G$ is the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb F_p$ (or more generally, over $\mathbb F_q$ for some prime power $q$). First of all, your claim about uniqueness of the faithful representation is false, see: [Character table of modular Heisenberg groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404571/character-table-of-modular-heisenberg-groups). I will outline a construction of them.

Fix some embedding $\chi\colon \mathbb F_q\hookrightarrow\mathbb C^\times$. Consider the normal subgroup
$$N=\begin{pmatrix}1&\mathbb F_q&\mathbb F_q\\
&1\\&&1\end{pmatrix}\subset G=\begin{pmatrix}1&\mathbb F_q&\mathbb F_q\\
&1&\mathbb F_q\\&&1\end{pmatrix},$$
which has a character $\theta\colon N\to\mathbb C^\times$.
$$\theta\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\
&1\\&&1\end{pmatrix}:=\chi(b).$$
Now let $\pi:=Ind_N^G\theta$.
An explicit Mackey computation shows $\pi$ is indeed irreducible. Moreover, we may explicitly compute the character of $\theta$, which is supported on $N$, as:
$$ch_\pi\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\
&1\\&&1\end{pmatrix}=\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_q}\chi(ax+b),$$
so in particular when $a=0$ we have $ch_\pi(a)=q\chi(x)$. In particular, since the character is defined over $\mathbb Q(\zeta_q)$, the division algebra $D_\pi$ corresponding to $\pi$ must be over $\mathbb Q(\zeta_q)$.

Moreover, from the construction of $\pi$ it is clear that it can be defined over $\mathbb Q(\zeta_q)$, so $D=\mathbb Q(\zeta_q)$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration.  This argument seems to match what I saw in these notes of Paul Garrett: https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/repns/notes_2014-15/05_finite_heisenberg_ssw.pdf

Just to be clear, it seems this line of reasoning shows that for the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_p$, there are $p-1$ faithful irreducible representations over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$.  However, to get a representation defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, you have to take the sum of all these representations, right?  Hence there is a unique faithful irreducible representation defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I agree about the uniqueness statement. There are p-1 Galois orbits of the representation defined above Q(zeta_p).

Comment: You can't embed the additive group of F_q for q a proper prime power in C^\times since a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic

Comment: Oops yes, let q=p. The argument in general looks identical, you just need to change a couple of words.